# Questions about make a spiral(or twisted) shaped building

Tags: modifiers

I've only been searching here for a while, but this is the first time I've asked a question.

I want to make a spiral building with a shape like the sketch below.
(Sorry for the owful sketch)

[image]

If divide it into large parts, I can divide them into this way. Maybe a few more parts.
[image]

What's the best way to create this type of building in Blender?

I tested various functions myself, and finally succeeded in making this.

[image]
[image]

The problem is that I don't understand why it worked so well.
I tried to apply the currently applied modifier to another object to add another part, but it didn't look like this at all.

Please help. Thanks!

================================================================
Reply to moonboots

After hearing your comments that I applied modifiers properly, I worked on those modifiers a bit more.

When I first asked the question, it was like this:
As such, the shape of the core part and the part to wrap the outside did not match.

[image]

When applying the warp modifier, the core part applied the falloff type smooth.
The same smooth was applied to the internal parts, so it didn't fit well.

So I applied the falloff as a curve and adjusted it until I got the right shape.
I can make it
As a result, I was able to apply it roughly in the shape I wanted.

[image]

If I want to make both objects in the same shape, probably need to make two objects the same size and apply the same value as a modifier.
As such, the original object size is different, so it seems difficult to apply exactly the same.
(Below is an object in its original state without any modifier applied.)

[image]

It's been tested enough, so I think I can try making it again with the details I want.

Thanks for the help!

================================================================
Reply to moonboots_2

In order to apply different textures to this later, I'm going to make two objects.
I haven't tested it by making it into a single object yet.

I have an additional question. Added photos to the original text.

In order to add the desired details, I tried again by this detailed object.
(object B)
Array and twist work fine, but warp doesn't work as expected.
[image]

I simply want to make an object that narrows in a curved shape.
What causes two objects with almost similar shapes to operate in different shapes?
Are there any other modifiers that can make this simpler?

================================================================
Reply to moonboots_3

I applied it like this. I like the results. thank you!

[image]

Comment: The Simple Deform modifier in Twist mode is a good choice to do this sort of object. When you say that you tried with another object and it didn't work, maybe share this second object so that we see why it didn't work this time?

Comment: The image was not attached to the comment, so I wrote the answer in the original text. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: if you use one object instead of 2 it doesn't go the way you want?

Comment: I added reply on the Again, I added a reply to the original text. For various reasons, I haven't tried working with one object yet.
A question was added.

Comment: You can have one object only and assign different textures if this is your problem.

Comment: If you look at the bottom image attached to the original text,
Both are modifiers applied to a single object, but with different results.
I also applied Object from / to as the same thing.

Comment: It's hard to follow, but have you tried Simple Deform (Twist) in order to twist the shape, then Lattice in order to make it narrow towards the top?

Answer (score 1):

What about this kind of object:

[image]

Give it an *Array* modifier on the Z axis, then the *Simple Deform* modifier/*Twist* mode in order to twist it vertically, and at last a *Lattice* modifier to make it narrow towards the top:

[image]

If you don't want the inner shape to be deformed then you'll need to separate this part and use another method like an array with an object offset (the object being an empty, and you'll lift and rotate the empty a bit on Z), here is what it gives before the lattice:

[image]

Comment: I tried it with the Lattice modifier as you advised.
The results were very good! (results are attached to the original text)
Since all the functions of Blender are new to me (actually, the 3D tool itself is the first for me), I found a way to handle it by searching.

The handling was simple. However, it was a little uncomfortable to operate everything manually.
It feels little unconvenient, but it felt more advantageous to create the exact shape I wanted.

It seems that the same method should be applied to outer objects. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: if you have any problem with the lattice, feel free to ask. You need to add Resolution on W, and don't scale its horizontal edge loops on Z (so press S+shift+Z) so that the lattice only deforms on X and Y. If you have a lot of horizontal edge loops (like in your last pictures) enable the Proportional Editing option