How to model a spiraling or helical building?
How can I model this spiraling or helical building? I have been trying to use the Screw modifier, but I am not getting the same result.



Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235114/questions-about-make-a-spiralor-twisted-shaped-building https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187019/piping-cream-through-a-piping-tip/187071#187071

@CarloVentimiglia Posting questions is no inconvenience, but please make them descriptive. Most of your posts use generic words like "how to model this", "how to fix this". I've commented on most of them before, please avoid using the word "this" in the title and body, try to make your posts descriptive by using relevant keywords. In the future, no one looking for similar answers will be able to find your posts by using search because there are no relevant keywords in them and they all look the same.

@CarloVentimiglia Another thing: if you keep on not accepting any answers in the future, the willingness to help you out might decrease over time.

Create a 6 vertex cylinder, scale it on Z, subdivide horizontally:

Give it a Simple Deform modifier, Bend mode, 180° (or whatever) on Z:

Give it Lattice modifier, create a lattice object, select the lattice in the cylinder's modifier, scale the lattice so that it encompass the cylinder, in the Data panel of the lattice add some resolution on W, in Edit mode scale down some edge loops of the lattice

Duplicate the cylinder and lattice. For the copy, apply the 2 modifiers, select the vertical edges and bevel:

Extrude Faces Along Normals:


Thank you very much for your help!

@CarloVentimiglia if this has resolved your problem, please mark the checkmark on the left of this post below the vote buttons. As Gordon has mentioned, if you keep on not accepting any answers in the future, the willingness to help you out might decrease over time.
